# (Laravel) Get data from a table which an ID correspond with another table that link with that table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I was playing around with my first Laravel project and my question above might be a little bit confusing but let me explain:-

I have 3 tables (actually I have more, but lets ignore it), I have `standards`, `stddetails` & `sections` as shown:-

[image: Databases]

So the foreign key corresponds are below:-

- column `stdPK` from table `standards` = column `stdFK` from table
  `stddetails`
- column `ssctionPK` from table `sections` = column `ssctionFK` from
  table `stddetails`

And the scenario is this:-

Lets say I **have an `$id` to be match on `stdPK` from table `standards`**. **With that `$id`**, I am required to **get all data from table `sections`**. The problem is, I can't find a right query for that as both `standards` and `sections` tables only linked with `stddetails` table.

Currently my query in my `web.php` is this:-

```
Route::get('getstddtl/{id?}', function ($id) {

     $stdsec = Section::
            leftJoin('stddetails', 'ssctionFK', '=', 'ssctionPK')
            ->join('standards', function($join) use ($id){
                $join->on('stdPK', '=', 'stdFK')
                        ->where('stdFK', $id);
            });

    return view('standarddtl', [
        'stdsec' => $stdsec

    ]);
});
```

I thought it should be easy, boy... I was wrong... I hoped someone can help me with this because my brain have very limited thinking capacity.

**UPDATE 1:-**

I have set the eloquent relationship in each model and uses Laravel's Eloquent method in retrieving the data:-

```
$stdsec = Stddetail::with('section')->find($id);
```

All data is retrieved from both `stddetails` & `sections` tables, the problem now is difficulty on displaying data from column `ssctionName` in `sections` table in a display page as it return an error.

The related code on the display page is below:-

```
@foreach ($stdsec as $task)
       {{strtoupper($task->ssctionName)}}
@endforeach
```

The error shown:-

[image: Error on display foreach]

I think the eloquent method is good, now the display part is giving me trouble. Any ideas on how to solve this?

**UPDATE 2:-**

Here's the models for each table:-

Table `standards` as **Standard** model:-

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Standard extends Model
{

    public $primaryKey = 'stdPK';

    public function stddetail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Stddetail::class, 'stdFK', 'stdPK');
    }
}
```

Table `stddetails` as **Stddetail** model:-

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stddetail extends Model
{
    public $table = "stddetails";
    public $primaryKey = 'sdtlPK';
    protected $fillable = ['stdFK', 'sdtlPgNo', 'sdtlLnNo', 'sdtlText', 'sdtlShrtnote', 'sdtlSchm', 'svrFK', 'ssctionFK', 'sdtlRefLbl'];

    public function standard()
    {   
        return $this->belongsTo(Standard::class, 'stdFK');
    }

    public function section()
    {   
        return $this->belongsTo(Section::class, 'ssctionFK');
    }

}
```

Table `sections` as **Section** model:-

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Section extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'ssctionPK';
    public function stddetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Stddetail::class, 'ssctionFK', 'ssctionPK');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how databased are intended to be used. But you could do some joins with the pk as foreign key.

Comment: Take a look at relations? Belongs to/has many?

Comment: @ThomasMoors Owh, didn't know that.. Actually there are lots of table which linked to each other, but on a page I am currently working on, uses those 3 tables..

Comment: @KirkBeard MySQL from XAMPP, sorry...

Comment: @senty I didn't look at the relations because it wasn't me created the database.. Is it crucial for querying?

Comment: @Kaydarin, yes, in relational database relations (foreign keys) become critical point..

Comment: @BagusTesa Alright.. noted..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at eloquent relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

You should be able to set proper relationships(hasMany, belongsTo, etc) between your models (tables) and get all data with a single command (Eloquent will create needed queries for you).

On an unrelated note, I would suggest improving your naming convention. It is really hard to understand event basic links with all acronyms and short names used

Comment: What do you mean "Eloquent will create needed queries for you"? I thought we need to create the queries ourselves... I did set the relationships in each table's model...

Comment: That the whole purpose of using ORM, like Eloquent. You are 'just' writing code, with so-called fluent syntax and if you got your relationships set up right, you would be able to get all data with just using Models.

Comment: For instance:
`$details = Standards::with('stddetails')->find($id);`
Would return standards model with a property _stddetails_ of collection type. 
You did not have to write SQL queries, Eloquent did that for you. Purpose of it is to abstract that layer from you so you can just write code
(Sorry about two comments, I hit enter too soon and SO won't let me edit the first comment)

Comment: I have read the documentation and set all the relations in each models but until the "Querying Relations", I don't get where the query supposed to be placed. Is it in the routes, controllers or models? Plus, back to my original question, if possible, could you provide me the query with the eloquent method? I'm kinda blurred with it...

Comment: @Kaydarin, you don't have to put a literal sql queries.. you only need 'eloquent' queries - you could put this everywhere (it's related to system design), but most of the time people put them into controllers. anyway, if you wish for the query in eloquent, you'll need a model first..

Comment: @BagusTesa Thank you, I have put the 'queries' in controller as you suggested and I have put the relationships in all of the related table and uses the eloquent method as suggested by Nerman. Now I have a new problem to display them...

Comment: @Kaydarin, care to post the model? and tried to `dd($stdsec)`

Comment: @BagusTesa done... Did it and it return all the data from both `stddetails` and `sections` with the `$id`. The query works but the displaying part is boggling me as my programming knowledge aren't very good at the moment...

Comment: ahhh! i see, i bet you think it works just like joins. but unfortunately not.. try `$task->section->ssctionName`. i thought you'll get some gist by looking at the `dd`'s result - oh well.