# Display the Name of Table using the ID of another table in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Please, I have a function in my controller.
I want to query the stock table to select the list of `product_id` and after `select`, it should go to product table to display the `NAME` of product to the user instead of `product_id`.

```
public function getStockList()
{
    $stock = DB::table("stocks")->pluck("product_id","product_id")->all();
    $products = DB::table("products")->pluck("name")->where('id', $stock);
    return view('shop.shop')->with(['stocks' => $stocks, 
    'stock' => $stock, 'products' => $products]);
}
```

**My PHP blade has**

```
{!! Form::select
(
    'stock',
    ['' => 'Select'] +$stock,'',
    array(
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'id'=>'country',
        'style'=>'width:350px;'
        )
)!!}

{!! Form::select
(
    'product_id',
    [''=>'Select Supplier'] + $products, null, 
    ['class'=>'form-control']
)!!}
```

Basically, I don't want `product_id` to be displayed to the user but the product name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Laravel) Get data from a table which an ID correspond with another table that link with that table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268591/laravel-get-data-from-a-table-which-an-id-correspond-with-another-table-that-l)

Comment: you can try join with products table

Comment: Hi Meera Tank, My app is a bit complex as I use jquery to auto fill other field based on the product_id selected by user. Hence when I use   `$stocks = DB::table('products')->join('stocks', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')
            ->select('products.name', 'stocks.product_id')->get();`  I did get same result. That's why I'm trying to use this method above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public function getStockList()
{
    $stock = DB::table("stocks")->pluck("product_id");
    $products = DB::table("products")->whereIn('id', $stock)->pluck("name","id");
    return view('shop.shop')->with([
        'stocks'   => $stocks,
        'stock'    => $stock,
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

Replace your product list select box with the following

```
{!! Form::select('product_id',$products,null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Select Products'])!!}
```

Comment: Thanks Hasan,  When I return $stock I get array of [1,1,3,4,4], and when I return $products I get empty array []. Hope you understand. $products should display  array of name in products table. Waiting for your kindly reply

Comment: Please confirm that [1,1,3,4,4] is your product id and is your stocks table has multiple stocks of same product? @Steve

Comment: Yes  [1,1,3,4,4] is product_id in the stock table! my stock table has multple stocks of same products because they are supplier by diff vendor.

Comment: Thanks Hasan, when i return $products  `{"1":"Station","3":"Module","4":"Reader"} which I think its okay BUT when I view the blade  `{!! Form::select('product_id', [''=>'Select Supplier'] + $products, null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}.` I'm getting Unsupported operand types

Comment: Problem is in your blade file. Check my updated answers@Steve

Answer (score 0):

you need array to pass in form

```
/* $product_array = ['1' => 'product 1',  '2' => 'product 2', '3' => 'product 3']; */
```

so in your controller

```
$product_array = []
  foreach($products as $product){
    $product_array[$product->id] = $product->name;
  }

return view('shop.shop')->with(['stocks' => $stocks, 
'stock' => $stock, 'products' => $products , 'product_array'=>$product_array]);
```

And in your view

```
{{!! Form::select('product_id', $product_array , null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!! }}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Tank, Did you mean I should write like this? `    public function getStockList()
    {
        $stocks = Stock::all()->Where('quantity', '>', '0');

        $stock = DB::table("stocks")->pluck("product_id", "product_id")->all();        $products = DB::table("products")->pluck("name")->where('id', $stock);
$product_array = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
$product_array[$product->id] = $product->name;
    }
return view('shop.shop')->with(['stocks' => $stocks, 'stock' => $stock, 'products' => $products, 'product_array' => $product_array]);
    }
`

Comment: @Steve i just want to say that you need to pass array of id And name in select to display name.